# Is it valid to use custom name in "target" attribute of <a> tag?

Tags: html, anchor, web-standards

I have code something like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
<a href="http://gmail.com" target="_blank">gmail</a>
```

Whenever I click one of the links, a new window or tab is created. I wanted the links to just use one.

So I changed my code like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="google">google</a>
<a href="http://gmail.com" target="google">gmail</a>
```

It worked! It makes a new window just the first time either link is clicked, and after that clicks on the links appear in that window.

I think this is good, but I cannot find something about this in the [W3C HTML 4 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2). Is it valid and cross-browser compatible?

Comment: It's valid by http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly how you would use it in this instance. The value of the `target` attribute specifies where to open the linked document and can be one of `_blank`, `_self`, `_parent`, `_top`, or *`framename`*, where *framename* would be the name of the frame or window to use.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is perfectly valid and browser-compatible. The `target` specifies the name of the target window (or frame), which will be opened when it does not already exist.

The following have special meanings: `_self`, `_blank`, `_parent`, `_top`

Maybe you need [a better HTML reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a).